# Android ListAdapter in Activity?

Tags: android, android-listview

Is this possible to use the ListAdapter extends activity class? If yes means let me know please. Otherwise, What is the alternate Way?

Comment: It doesn't seem like the way to go. You probably want to extend the [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) class instead. You should perhaps take the time for a close look at the android MVP/MVC design pattern. This [google presentation](http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/gwt-testing-best-practices.pdf) contains some valuable informations.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible to make a class that extends `Activity` and implements the `ListAdapter` interface, but there is no reason to do this. Instead, you would instantiate an implementation of the `ListAdapter` inside your `Activity`. `ListAdapter` would provide data for a list, whereas an `Activity` is essentially a "page" in your application.

Instead, you could use the already existing `ListActivity` to make an activity that displays a list powered by a `ListAdapter`. See "Binding to Data" in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html.